# MapOnClickListener doesn't seems to work

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I'm writing an application using Kotlin and GoogleMap. I've got the map and I tried to set an OnMapClick listener that only logs a message. The build is ok, but when I click on the map, nothing happens.
 I've looked for documentation but I found nothing about a problem like this.
Here the code of the map:

```
class map : FragmentActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {
     private var mMap: GoogleMap? = null

     override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
         mMap = googleMap
         mMap?.setOnMapClickListener {
             GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener { p0 -> Log.d("Map", p0.toString()) }
         }
     }
}
```

I found a lot of documentation about GoogleMap in Java, but nothing in Kotlin, so I tried this by my own. Thanks for helping me to find what's wrong with this code.

Comment: Try to change the code to `setOnMapClickListener(GoogleMap.on[...])`

Comment: It works, thank you, I didn't even though about this.

Comment: You're welcome. I made this an answer which you can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re passing a lambda to `setOnMapClickListener` by using `{}`. In fact, you simply want to pass the `GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener` as an argument, which will work with parentheses. So change your code to `setOnMapClickListener(GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener())`

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways to do this.

Method 1: Make a listener var and pass it in

```
val mapCickListener = object : GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {
        override fun onMapClick(p0: LatLng?) {
            Log.d("Map_Tag", "CLICK")
        }
    }

    map.setOnMapClickListener(mapCickListener) //Note. Use () and not {}
```

Method 2. Just pass in the object in the call.

```
  map.setOnMapClickListener(object : GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {
        override fun onMapClick(p0: LatLng?) {
            Log.d("Map_Tag", "CLICK")
        }
    })
```